# Multiple tags on Emacs agenda search

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm defining a custom link property using `org-agenda`. The idea is to create a new link type that can find matching tags. I've added the following configs on my Emacs personal configuration (I'm using Doom):

```
(after! org
  ...other configs
  (org-add-link-type "tag" 'follow-tag-link)
)

...

;;
;; ORG LINKS
(defun follow-tag-link (tag)
  (org-tags-view (null current-prefix-arg) tag))
```

them, I've created this sample document:

```
#+TITLE: C3PO Architecture
#+FILETAGS: c3po

* HTTP                :http:

Try it: [[tag:c3po:http][http requests]]
```

If I try it with command, using: `SPC-o-a-m` and them typing: `c3po:http` I can see it on my agenda. But, if I try to use my function (on the Try it part of the document) I go to the agenda view, with the same tag query, but no result =/

Can anybody help me? I really need it because I have multiple projects and it would be nice to be able to filter by file during tag search

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `follow-tag-link` to **only** list TODOs when called *without* a prefix.

So, you should see results (w/o prefix) with headlines such as,

```
* TODO HTTP :http:
```

or swap the prefix behaviour of your function

```
(defun follow-tag-link (tag)
  (org-tags-view current-prefix-arg tag))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: @odelucca: if this answer has solved your problem, then please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it, by clicking the check mark to the left.